# Using itertools.product for different sizes of items

Tags: python, loops

Let's say I have a list of lists, like so:

```
[
  ["A", "B"],
  ["C", "D", "E"]
]
```

I want to get all possible permutations, which in this case gives me 6 results.

Later, that list gets a new item appended to it:

```
[
  ["A", "B"],
  ["C", "D", "E"],
  ["F", "G"]
]
```

I want to use itertools.product to get that set of combos as well, automatically including the new list item.

(This would all be easier if itertools.product took a list of items to combine.)

Is this possible?

Comment: "I want to use itertools.product to get that set of combos as well, automatically including the new list item." <- But what's the problem in just doing that?

Comment: e.g. `itertools.product(*your_updated_list_of_lists)`.

Comment: You have a list that contains the arguments that you want to pass separately; that is what the `*` operator is for, as in the linked duplicate.

Comment: in short, if you have that lists as a variable called `myLists`, you would just call `itertools.product(*myLists)`

Comment: Because I never knew what that star operator was even for. Thank y'all!